# Unit testing an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ng-html2js

I'm trying to unit test all the directives using karma and jasmine. When I try to load a directive, which has a template called `header.html`, I get the following error: `Error: Unexpected request: GET header.html No more request expected`

http://plnkr.co/edit/YTUFXCMdK5JFEwMzzXaR?p=preview

**Update:
I have the following config in karma.conf.js:**

```
files: [
      'test/client/specs/main.js',
      // 'WebContent/modules/common/header/**/*.html',
      {pattern: 'WebContent/libs/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'WebContent/modules/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'WebContent/modules/common/header/tmpl/*.html', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/client/specs/**/*spec.js', included: false}
    ],


    // generate js files from html templates
    preprocessors: {
      'WebContent/modules/common/header/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },


    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      'moduleName': 'Templates',
      cacheIdFromPath: function(filepath) {
        return filepath.match(/\/WebContent\/modules\/common\/header\/.*\.html/);
      }
    },
```

I'm trying to load it by:

```
beforeEach(function() {
      module("Templates");
    });
```

Now i get the following errors:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Templates due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Templates' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/nomod?p0=Templates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in my unit tests by injecting the $templateCache into the test and then putting the html into the cache.

http://plnkr.co/edit/btgYfiiRzacS6MfPFlbv?p=preview

I researched a few different approaches, and we settled on putting the html into the directive.

```
template: "<div>This is the template</div>"
```

It makes it much easier to test as you no longer need to update the templateCache in the unit test, which is a pain in the ass and error prone when you have a big piece of html in your directive.

Comment: Yea but I want to test all of my external templates. Sometimes I end up changing my templates when working with my source code. I don't want to put all of my templates in my unit test code.

Comment: Like I said then the least painful way is to put them in the directive directly (no pun intended). Feels a bit shitty though to put the html and JS together, but the benefits from unit testing seems to out weigh  the other bad points.

Comment: I agree with you. At least I have it working right now. I was wondering what if I use $http to fetch the templates and put them in $templateCache in my unit test code one template at a time.

Comment: Could be an idea... I havent tried something like that, but it def seems to make the unit tests a bit more complex having to deal with asynchronous issues...

Comment: Meanwhile I will accept your answer and work with this. Thanks.

Comment: So far for us its worked great! When I find the even cleaner solution I will be sure to share it with you!

Answer (score 1):

The Karma way is to load the template html dynamically into $templateCache. You could just use `html2js` karma pre-processor, as explained [here](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing/blob/master/test/tabsSpec.js)

This boils down to adding templates '*.html' to your files in the conf.js file
as well

```
preprocessors = {
  '*.html': 'html2js'
};
```

and use

```
beforeEach(module('..'));

beforeEach(module('...html', '...html'));
```

into your js testing file